# Updating Visual Studio leaves my app critically wounded

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I updated the Visual Studio Developer tools and voila! Some of my code no longer functions. I can debug, but 90% of the fixes I had made in the past day disapears whenever I debug. It worked earlier today with the old Visual Studio; but now, the effects of the code simply don't show up when I debug.

I can see the code in the code-editing window, but it doesn't debug any way I try. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

P.S. If this belongs on SuperUser, I'll be happy to put it there. Simply tell me, and I'll move it.

Comment: To the one person who voted to close as off topic: Did you even read the whole question? I explicitly said to *please tell me if you think it belongs on SuperUser.* Also, the FAQ specifically designates questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" as on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually clean the solution and output folders (by deleting the obj and bin folders while Studio is closed).  Re-open and rebuild.  If it's in a referenced DLL, drop the reference in the consumer, build to get a failure, then re-add.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This also fixed my problem where I could only edit the app from one computer.